# Dealing with dates and times in R

Tags: datetime, r

I have a data frame with 2 columns, the first containing dates, and the second containing times, in the format:

```
     date         time        
[1,] "2003-10-03" "22:32:00"
[2,] "2003-10-05" "17:43:06"
[3,] "2003-10-10" "18:45:56"
[4,] "2003-11-12" "17:07:16"
[5,] "2003-11-13" "12:48:04"
[6,] "2003-11-13" "18:17:57"
```

I would like to create some histograms of these data looking at the number of events per year, per months and at a specific hour of the day.

For the year that's easy

```
hist(as.Date(df[,1]), "years")
```

Now, to get the number of events per months (disregarding the year) I used:

```
 months = c("January", "February", "March", 
            "April", "May", "June", "July", 
            "August", "September", "October", 
            "November", "December")
 tb <- table(factor(months.Date(dt), levels=months)
 barplot(tb)
```

Questions:

1. Is there a nicer way to do the histogram per month?
2. How do I do the same thing for the time of the day (hourly bins are sufficient)?

Thanks

Comment: No need to list out the month names - remember that `month.name` and `month.abb` are already built-in and use your system's default language.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would use xts, especially if you have data other than dates and times in your data.frame.

```
df$count <- 1
x <- xts(df$count,as.POSIXct(paste(df$date,df$time)))

# create aggregates and plot with plot.zoo()
plot.zoo(period.apply(x, endpoints(index(x),"years"), sum), type="h")
plot.zoo(period.apply(x, endpoints(index(x),"quarters"), sum), type="h")
plot.zoo(period.apply(x, endpoints(index(x),"months"), sum), type="h")
plot.zoo(period.apply(x, endpoints(index(x),"weeks"), sum), type="h")
plot.zoo(period.apply(x, endpoints(index(x),"days"), sum), type="h")
plot.zoo(period.apply(x, endpoints(index(x),"hours"), sum), type="h")
```

Comment: seems interesting, I'll have a go at it!

Answer (score 4):

If you don't mind the labels being "01" instead of "January" you could do something like this

```
barplot(table(format(df$date,"%m")))
```

Comment: Good idea.  Note that `"%B"` provides full month names and `"%b"` the abbreviations.  See `?strptime` for all the conversion specifications.

Comment: Well, I don't care about names, I will hide the axis and rewrite them anyway because I don't need them in English :)

Comment: I didn't like the idea of %B or %b because you lose the natural ordering of the months.